# Is weak pointer locking lock-free?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic

Seeing that shared_ptrs are thread-safe and can have shared ownership over different threads using the lock-free std::atomic. Is the lock() function on a weak ptr made from this shared_ptr lock-free?

Comment: It can be done so, but you would have to look at your implementation to be sure.

Comment: How do i check whether the lock function is lock-free?

Comment: Build for debug, and step thru the code with a debugger looking for locks - or look for it using atomic. You can also just look at the source in your editor, but C++ library code can be really hard to follow.

Comment: Are you asking if it is thread safe?

Comment: @LokiAstari -- no, it's about lock-free. Thread safety deals with correctness-- ensuring that threads don't step on each others' data. Lock-free is about progress guarantees -- if the thread that holds a lock gets suspended by the kernel, everyone waiting for that lock also in effect gets suspended; in a lock-free implementation, thread safety is ensured through user-level atomics, so the synchronization code cannot be suspended.

Comment: I'm asking because i would like to share an object with an audio thread that should not own it.